# Custom Drag And Drop UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I need to create a custom drag and drop. I created two listview and in the first one through the pointer pressed event I created the drag with a customized image. The only thing that is missing is: to succeed in having the event dragover or the event pointerentered in the grid of the item of the second listview. This does not work because when this should occur, the moved event is still active.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Drag_And_Drop_Custom_UWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="using:Drag_And_Drop_Custom_UWP"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Loaded="Page_Loaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <local:DrugPosition x:Name="CoordinatesDrug"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="BaseGrid">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewPerson" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListPerson}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemRevealStyleDrug}" Margin="50">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridPerson" Background="Red" PointerPressed="GridPerson_PointerPressed">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewHeight" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListHeight}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemRevealStyleDrug}" Margin="50" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Characteristic">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridHeight" Background="Red" AllowDrop="True" 
                          PointerEntered="GridHeight_PointerEntered"
                          PointerExited="GridHeight_PointerExited"
                          DragEnter="GridHeight_DragEnter"
                          DragLeave="GridHeight_DragLeave">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PersonHeight}" Margin="5"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="GridForDrop">
        <Grid x:Name="GridLetter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="-128,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Background="#FF18AA30">
            <TextBlock Text="C" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="72"/>
        </Grid>
        <Image x:Name="ImageToDrugOver" Canvas.Left="{x:Bind CoordinatesDrug.LeftDrugPosition, Mode=OneWay}" Canvas.Top="{x:Bind CoordinatesDrug.TopDrugPosition, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Characteristic
{
    public int PersonHeight { get; set; }
}
public class DrugPosition : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double leftDrugPosition;
    public double LeftDrugPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return leftDrugPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            leftDrugPosition = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LeftDrugPosition)));
        }
    }

    private double topDrugPosition;
    public double TopDrugPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return topDrugPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            topDrugPosition = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TopDrugPosition)));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> ListPerson = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    ObservableCollection<Characteristic> ListHeight = new ObservableCollection<Characteristic>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListPerson.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 1" });
        ListPerson.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 2" });
        ListPerson.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 3" });
        ListPerson.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 4" });
        ListPerson.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person 5" });

        ListHeight.Add(new Characteristic() { PersonHeight = 100 });
        ListHeight.Add(new Characteristic() { PersonHeight = 200 });
        ListHeight.Add(new Characteristic() { PersonHeight = 100 });
        ListHeight.Add(new Characteristic() { PersonHeight = 200 });
        ListHeight.Add(new Characteristic() { PersonHeight = 100 });
    }

    private async void GridPerson_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid GridPersona = sender as Grid;
        Point puntopressd = e.GetCurrentPoint(BaseGrid).Position;
        BitmapImage ImageToDrug = await LoadImageForDrug();
        CoordinatesDrug.LeftDrugPosition = puntopressd.X - 50;
        CoordinatesDrug.TopDrugPosition = puntopressd.Y - 50;
        ImageToDrugOver.Source = ImageToDrug;

        PointerEventHandler moved = null;
        moved = (s, args) =>
        {
            BaseGrid.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
            Point puntomoved = e.GetCurrentPoint(BaseGrid).Position;
            CoordinatesDrug.LeftDrugPosition = puntomoved.X - 50;
            CoordinatesDrug.TopDrugPosition = puntomoved.Y - 50;

        };

        PointerEventHandler released = null;
        released = (s, args) =>
        {
            Point puntoreleas = e.GetCurrentPoint(BaseGrid).Position;
            ImageToDrugOver.Source = null;
            BaseGrid.PointerMoved -= moved;
            BaseGrid.PointerReleased -= released;
        };
        BaseGrid.PointerMoved += moved;
        BaseGrid.PointerReleased += released;
    }

    private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImageForDrug()
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await rtb.RenderAsync(GridLetter);

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var buffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();

        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
            (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            buffer.ToArray());
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        return img;
    }

    private void GridHeight_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid GridHeight = sender as Grid;
        GridHeight.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }

    private void GridHeight_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid GridHeight = sender as Grid;
        GridHeight.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    private void GridHeight_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid GridHeight = sender as Grid;
        GridHeight.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }

    private void GridHeight_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid GridHeight = sender as Grid;
        GridHeight.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

How could I make the dragover event work, or rather in this case pointer entered (in the second listview) even while moving the image and the moved event of the first listview is active?

Always thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement **Drag and Drop** operation in UWP, you need to do the following steps:

> 1. Enable dragging on an element by setting its CanDrag property to true.
> 2. Build the data package. The system handles images and text automatically, but for other content, you'll need to handle the DragStarted and DragCompleted events and use them to construct your own data package.
> 3. Enable dropping by setting the AllowDrop property to true on all the elements that can receive dropped content.
> 4. Handle the DragOver event to let the system know what type of drag operations the element can receive.
> 5. Process the Drop event to receive the dropped content.

More information, please see [Drag and Drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/drag-and-drop) document.

Here's the UWP official [Drag and drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) for your details.

Comment: I know this, but I needed to create this custom drag and drop.

Comment: @Ticras The document has expalined that if you want make your custom drag and drop, 'you can implement your own version by using the APIs in the [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DragDrop.Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.dragdrop.core) namespace'.

Comment: Is it possible to have... a small example? Because I do not know where to start...

Comment: @Ticras Could you please tell me your detailed requirements? Because I check your above code, it's just the general drag and drop operation. I did not find that there're some specific operations. So, I did not understand why the general drag and drop operation doesn't meet your requirement.

Comment: I wanted to customize the drag image on the listview item