# C#| How to implement drag and drop functionality in WinUI 3 / UWP with custom DataPackage

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, drag-and-drop, winui-3

I'm using a Drag and drop service implemented in the Microsoft template studio ([explanation here](https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/blob/release/docs/UWP/features/drag-and-drop.md)). I think, I understand the way it works, and already read the documentation about the basic Drag and drop tool provided by Microsoft, but still don't know, how could I customize my DD.

I'd like to transfer an object derived from a custom class by moving a UIElement with DD, and according to Microsoft's documentation I should customize a DataPackage somehow. My problem is, that I don't really understand, where and how can I wrap my custom object into a DataPackage.

I think the authors of the following questions had a very similar issue:

1. [It is unclear how to create a custom DataPackage for drag-and-drop #2669](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2669)
2. [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222137/custom-drag-and-drop-uwp)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What about convert the custom class into a JSON string and pass the string instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can "package" any custom (data) object via the .Properties collection of the DataPackage object in the DragStartEventArgs (args) parameter (DragStarting event); e.g.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

// .Properties is a <string,object> dictionary.
args.Data.Properties.Add( "FooData", foo );
```

Recover the object in the Drop event of the target via the DataPackageView object in the DragEventArgs (e) parameter; e.g.

```
var foo = e.DataView.Properties[ "FooData" ] as Foo;
```

Comment: What is particularly useful about this is the fact that DataPackageView.Properties can be accessed synchronously, unlike the other methods for getting data out of a DataPackageView. This is useful for testing the type of data and setting e.Handled = true in  TreeViewItem.OnDragOver( e) in order to suppress dropping when the data type is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to custom data, DataPackage supports only implementations of IRandomAccessStream and scalar types, string included here.  You can find more details [here](http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/c-sharp/winrt-datapackage-custom-objects).

You have two options: put your data in an instance of IRandomAccessStream, or in a string.  The former is suitable for large amounts of data.  Let's assume we use the latter for simplicify.

```
private void DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
{
     string data = SerializeMyData();          
     e.Data.SetData("MyDataFormat", objData);
}
```

Points of importance:

- SerializeMyData is a method which converts you objects to a string, it can be XML, JSON, whatever.
- "MyDataFormat" is an identifier which you will use to find your data.  Mind you, the clipboard / drag & drop / sharing mechanism supports multiple data types and content be transferred at once. For example, Word puts a copy selection as its own formatted type, plain text, RTF text, HTML text, all at once.

Then in the drop target, get the data of your own format:

```
private async void Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = await e.Data.GetView().GetDataAsync("MyDataFormat"); 
    //Deserialize it anyway you wish.           
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in the other response, DataPackage.Properties can be used to store objects directly in the data package.