# WinUI3 : how to know which uielement was dropped in UIElement.drop() event

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui-3

I'm working on a WinUI3 desktop application with c++. I was trying to perform a drag-and-drop operation. When I drop a textbox on a canvas I get a drop event from the canvas. In that drop event, as a sender, we can get a reference to the canvas instance[ the UIElement on which the drop happened ], but how to know which element was dropped on the canvas?

I came across [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/drag-and-drop#process-the-drop-event) on how to process drop events, but it's unclear how to pass data between dragstaring and drop events.

It would be of great help if you could help me understand which UIElement was dropped when we receive UIElement.drop() event

Thank you

Comment: Although the doc (which is a UWP doc, not a WinUI3 doc which in many cases cannot be found...) says *"In most cases, the system will construct a data package for you. The system automatically handles: Images,  Text"*, I think this doesn't work for WinUI3 for some reason (maybe it depends on app identity, packaging, security, etc.). So you must hook the DragStarting event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.dragstarting?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) and put what you want in it so you will get it back in the Drop event.

Comment: Thank you for your response @SimonMourier. I tried hooking up to both the DragStarting[from drag source] and Drop[from drop destination] events but I was not able to pass the data between them, In the drop event I was not able to get which element was dropped on drop destination.

Comment: In any case, you can't get the source element from a drag & drop operation, unless you put yourself any information you find suitable about it in the Data object. D&D can only contain serializable data (text, image bits, a stream, etc.), it's a general OS feature that can/must work across processes.

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier, Can you please help me with an example how to construct a dataobject?, I went over this link - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189724/c-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-functionality-in-winui-3-uwp-with-custom-da) but was not able to clearly figure out how to construct a serialized data package and receive it at drop event

Comment: Just use one of the SetXXX methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage or post what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I tried SetText, and it worked. had to use GetResults with GetTextAsync to get the text passed in the dragstaring event. can you please post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you, I appreciate your help @SimonMourier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [Drag and drop documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/drag-and-drop#construct-a-data-package) (which is a UWP doc, not a WinUI3 doc which in many cases cannot be found...) says

> In most cases, the system will construct a data package for you. The
> system automatically handles: Images, Text

This doesn't work for WinUI3 for some reason (maybe it depends on app identity, packaging, security, etc.), there's nothing constructed automatically in the target data object.

So you must hook the [DragStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.dragstarting) event and put what you want in it so you will get it back in the [Drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.drop) event.

You can't put/get the source element itself as an object from a drag & drop operation, you must put yourself some information you find suitable about it in the [Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.drageventargs.data) object. D&D as a general OS feature only supports serializable or well-known data (text, image bits, a stream, etc.).

To do that you can use one of the `SetXXX` methods of the [DataPackage class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage), like [SetText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.settext) for example.